# Is there a way to skip over table when it hasn't been filled with value

Tags: python, django, backend

I'm still learning Django python and trying to create webapp that display students scores each semester.
And I got this error that says `Grades2 matching query does not exist.`. Because I create separate class for each semester, and for this student I intentionally left second semester's score empty because in they haven't reach that semester yet.

with this models:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Students(models.Model):
    clas    = models.CharField(max_length=6, default='no data')
    nim     = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    year    = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.nim} in class {self.clas}"

class Grades1(models.Model):
    nim     = models.ForeignKey(Students, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    biology = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    math = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    history = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.nim.name} with scores \n biology = {self.biology} \n math = {self.math} \n history = {self.history}"

class Grades2(models.Model):
    nim     = models.ForeignKey(Students, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    biology = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    math = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    history = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.nim.name} with scores \n biology = {self.biology} \n math = {self.math} \n history = {self.history}"
    
class Achievement(models.Model):
    nim     = models.ForeignKey(Students, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ach     = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    scales   = [
        ('INT', 'INTERNATIONAL'),
        ('NA', 'NATIONAL'),
        ('RE', 'REGIONAL'),
        ('LO', 'LOCAL'),
        ('DE', 'DEED')
    ]
    scale  = models.CharField(
        max_length=3, 
        choices=scales,
        default='DE'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        if self.ach is not None:
            return f"{self.nim.name} has achieve {self.ach}"
        else :
            return f"{self.nim.name} has not achieve any championship"

class Accounts(models.Model):
    nim     = models.ForeignKey(Students, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    passwords   = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    email   = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.nim.name} use {self.email}"
```

and this views :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from . models import Students, Achievement, Grades1, Grades2
# Create your views here.

def index(response):
    return render(response, 'index.html', {})

def users(response, int):
    s = Students.objects.get(nim=int)
    sg1 = s.grades1_set.get(nim=int)
    sg2 = s.grades2_set.get(nim=int)
    sa = s.achievement_set.all()
    sac = s.accounts_set.get(nim=int)
    return render(response, 'users/user.html', {
        's' : s,
        'sg1' : sg1,
        'sg2' : sg2,
        'sa' : sa,
        'sac' : sac
        }
    )
```

specifically the error says :

```
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Grades2 matching query does not exist.
```

this error is in the views.py file

And my goal is for this webapp, if student hasn't reach certain semester, the data would simply states 'No Data' or some other thing, and not return this error.
So how can I automatically skip over any class(in views.py) if there is still empty data on it? Or is there a better solution to approach this goal?
Thank You

Comment: Use query filters or a try/except block to handle empty queries. Learn more about `get` method here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get